# What's the difference between CLBeacon and CBcentralManager

Tags: ios, ibeacon, cbcentralmanager, ios-bluetooth

I want to detects beacon/ibeacon devices near my iphone's proximity. I am not sure which class i should use

Should i use CLBeacon and CLBeaconRegion and start monitoring region

OR

Should i use CBcentralManager and scanForPeripheralsWithServices

Which api suited best for which use case ?

I have tried to find it online but it's not documented anywhere

Answer (score 3):

Although iBeacons use Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE), they are not treated as a BLE peripheral in iOS.  They are handled via the CoreLocation framework, so the classes you need are `CLLocationManager`, `CLRegion` and `CLBeacon`.  Refer to the [Core Location Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH9-SW7)

CBCentralManager is for BLE peripherals such as heart rate monitors, fitness trackers (or anything else you can think of where you want to exchange data with the peripheral)

Comment: This is correct.  What is more, CoreBlietooth cannot be used to detect iBeacons.

Answer (score 0):

CLBeacon and CLBeaconRegion are handy and able to get information in background.

CBcentralManager is not only for BLE, it can detect other legacy bluetooth device like mouse, keyboard, etc.